# elFinder and asp.net - unable to connect to backend

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following the author installation procedure, but I still can't have it working. I'm using asp.net mvc 4 and visual studio 2010.

I added the reference and added the necessary configuration into the root web.config.

Here is my root web.config file

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="elFinder" type="elFinder.Connector.Config.AppConnectorConfig, elFinder.Connector" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <elFinder apiVersion="2.0"
    localFSRootDirectoryPath="C:\SVN\DataExport\Wellman\Wellman\Upload"
    localFSThumbsDirectoryPath="C:\SVN\DataExport\Wellman\Wellman\Upload\.thumbs"
    rootDirectoryName="Root"
    uploadMaxSize="20M"
    defaultVolumeName="LocalFileSystem"
    baseUrl="http://localhost:57014/upload/"
    baseThumbsUrl="http://localhost:57014/upload/.thumbs/">
    duplicateFilePattern="Copy of {0}"
    duplicateDirectoryPattern="Copy of {0}"
    thumbsSize="48,48"
  </elFinder>
```

added the global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("Wellman.Controllers");

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // register IoC
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // add other registrations...
        // add elFinder connector registration
        builder.RegisterElFinderConnector();
        // create container
        IContainer _container = builder.Build();
        // need also to set container in elFinder module
        _container.SetAsElFinderResolver();
    }
```

and the routeconfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("elfinder.connector");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "LogOff",
            url: "logout/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOff", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

May be it late, but try fix '>' location:

```
<elFinder apiVersion="2.0"
    localFSRootDirectoryPath="c:\users"
    localFSThumbsDirectoryPath="c:\users\.thumbs"
    rootDirectoryName="Root"
    uploadMaxSize="20M"
    defaultVolumeName="LocalFileSystem"
    baseUrl="http://localhost:55470/data/"
    baseThumbsUrl="http://localhost:55470/data/.thumbs/"
    duplicateFilePattern="Copy of {0}"
    duplicateDirectoryPattern="Copy of {0}"
    thumbsSize="48,48">
</elFinder>
```